# Suppose that $f$ is continuous and increasing on $[a,b]$. If $E$ is a subset of $[a,b]$ and is nonempty, show that $\sup_{x\in E} f(x) = f(\sup E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and increasing on $[a,b]$. If $E$ is a subset of $[a,b]$ and is nonempty, show that $\sup_{x\in E} f(x) = f(\sup E)$.

I know since $f$ is increasing, there is a $c$ in $[a,b]$ where $f(c) < f(c+)$ and $f(c-) < f(c)$. I don't know if this will help me or not. Help!

Comment: 1. What did you try? 2. Is this homework?

Comment: 1. I assumed E was bounded from above so I let h = supE, and then concluded that f(c) must be greater than supE. And I got stuck here.

Comment: 2. Yes, this is a hw

Comment: You do not *assume* $E$ is bounded, you "prove" it by exhibit the bound.

Comment: Okay, I can do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c=\sup E$.  Because $f$ is in increasing, and $c\ge x$ for all $x\in E$, $f(c)\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in E$.  So, $f(c)$ is an upper bound for $f(E)$.

On the other hand, let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is a $d\in E$ such that $c-\epsilon<d\le c$. So, $f(c-\epsilon)<f(d)\le f(c)$. Therefore $f(c)=\sup f(E)$.

Comment: The above answer is 100% wrong.

Tim I know the question is boring but consider why continuity is needed and the definition of supremum of a set.

To the rest, does anything pass for proof on here these days? Seriously 4 upvotes and the question asker selected this answer.

Comment: Well it's not 100% wrong. But you are right that my answer is incorrect.

Comment: Ok a bit harsh, mostly frustrated with the numerosity of careless readers these days.

Comment: I did use the definition of $\sup$ but not the continuity. So, I've really only shown $f(\sup E)$ is an upper bound of $f(E)$. Looks like I'm guilty of being a bit careless as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and let $s = \sup E$. Since $f$ is continuous at $s$ there is $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(s)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-s|<\delta$. By definition of the supremum there is $x_0 \in E$ so that $s-\delta<x_0 \leq s$. Since $f$ is increasing we have that $f(s)-\varepsilon<f(x_0) \leq f(s)$. Therefore $f(s)=\sup_{x \in E} f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity, $$\lim_{x\to \sup E^-}f(x)=f(\sup E).$$ 
Since $f$ is increasing, if $x\in E$ $$\lim_{x\to \sup E^-}f(x)=\sup \{f(x)\mid x\in E\}=\sup f(E).$$

Finally,$$\sup f(E)=f(\sup E).$$